# Nested definition within a struct

Tags: c, struct, hashtable, nested-function

As far as nested functions go, I'm having trouble understanding what the input and outputs for
`unsigned long int(*hash)(char *);`
are...
Is this nested function taking in a string and outputting a pointer to an unsigned long int?

Thank you!

```
struct hash_table {
  unsigned long int(*hash)(char *);
  unsigned int n_buckets;
  sll **buckets; /* an array of pointers to string lists */
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned long int(*hash)(char *);
```

is a function pointer .

[How function pointers work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: thank you. And if I wanted to malloc this pointer to the heap, how much memory should I allocate to accommodate for this?

Comment: @Leeho Lim Just in case: are you sure you want to allocate **pointer**? I mean if you have a `struct hash_table variable;`, you already have the pointer inside the variable. The only thing left to do is to assign some appropriate function address to that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The `hash` member in the structure is not a nested function, it's a function pointer.

A function pointer is simply a pointer to a function (as the name implies). Since all you can do with functions in C is to call them or take their address, you never need to allocate memory for the function itself.

You can just initialize it with the address of a suitable function, which might look like:

```
static unsigned long int my_hash(char *s)
{
  return (unsigned long int) *s; /* Very bad hashing! */
}
```

Then elsewhere:

```
struct hash_table ht;
ht.hash = my_hash;
```

Note that the `&` (address of) operator isn't needed, since there are no parentheses after the name `my_hash`, the name of the function evaluates to its address.